# removing startup item from com.apple.launchd

Tags: osx, startup

Im not sure if this is the right place for this kind of question, but here it goes anyways...

I installed a program a few months ago, it had a startup option that I did install. Later, I decided to remove the program, but it seems to have left the startup script or item even after I uninstalled it.... and its trying to start every few seconds.

How can I remove this item?

Here is it from the console

```
$ com.apple.launchd[1] (com.jft.PdaNetMac[24476]): Exited with exit code: 1
$ com.apple.launchd[1] (com.jft.PdaNetMac): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear, that one turns out to be evil.

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jft.PdaNetMac.plist
$ sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jft.PdaNetMac.plist
```

The evil part is they have no business putting it in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`, which is reserved for services provided with OSX; it *should* have been in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! but the first command is unsuccessful...

<pre><code>
petros$ sudo launchctl unload -w com.jft.PdaNetMac
launchctl: Couldn't stat("com.jft.PdaNetMac"): No such file or directory
nothing found to unload
</code></pre>

Comment: Also... what does you mean by evil? Is it doing something bad?

Comment: Sorry, I switched gears somewhere in there; you have to use the same path that is then `rm`ed.  And the "evil" is that third party applications are not supposed to touch anything under `/System/Library` directly, because it belongs specifically to the OSX installation and a system update may modify or remove anything put there by someone else without warning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of their evilness... ;) I cant find the files in finder though. What else can I do to find these?

Comment: Interesting.  That's all I found from my local PDANet installation.  You cound run "sudo find /System/Library /Library -name com.jft.\*" in a Terminal window to see if it's somewhere else on yours.